# How to mirror/copy changes to other side of mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, mirror, shape-keys

I am working on making a shape key for my mesh to blink. I did one side and am now trying to duplicate the changes to the other side. Is there a way I can just copy everything from the left side of my mesh and apply all the same changes to the right side?

I know there is a mirror option but the vertices on the right and left sides are slightly different due to previous blinking iterations so I was hoping to just copy everything over.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZDB2.jpg

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of fancy options, but perhaps the simplest and least likely to cause unwanted issues, that will serve you well as a basic tool long into the future, is to just **duplicate the vertices and scale by -1.**

Please note, you can also just use the mirror tool (see link below), but this method does not depend on having other vertices selected, so it is more versatile.

1. Delete the vertices on the bad side.
2. Set the 3D cursor to the middle of the head.
3. select the good vertices (the mirror of the ones you deleted) (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>).
4. <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to duplicate.
5. Set pivot to 3D cursor
6. <kbd>s</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>-1</kbd> to flip over the X axis.
7. <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> to merge the doubles.

Some of the other options are:

- Delete half and use mirror modifier.
- Symmetrize in edit mode.
- Mesh -> [mirror](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/mirror.html) <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> in edit mode.